# Converting String timestamp to Scala Timestamp with Timezone throws Unparseable exception

Tags: scala, simpledateformat, timestamp-with-timezone

I am working with Timestamps in String format. And trying to convert them to a Timestamp Value. It is throwing an exception for me.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here:

```
val s = "2017-12-14T09:54:52.662-06:00"
val format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")

val ts = new Timestamp(format.parse(s).getTime)

Throws: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-12-14T09:54:52.662-06:00"
```

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. `Timestamp` is outdated too. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you use wrong pattern. Try to print `format.format(new Date())` and you will see.

Right pattern:

```
val format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
```